# Unable to stop Timer in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

Hi all I have used timer class to call an event after a minute here is my code

```
   public partial class TimerScheduler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        _timer.Enabled=false;
    }
}
```

but as I click start button timer works fine and after every minute it gets called but as I try to stop it it does not work And the _timer_Elapsed events gets called after every 1 minute

Comment: That's strange, because according to your code the timer would fire every 10 seconds. And why's the timer event method static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily make the timer fire only once by setting `AutoReset = false`. Then you'd have to restart the timer manually in the timer's event handler.

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);  
bool timerStarted = false;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Enabled = true;
    _timer.AutoReset = false;
    timerStarted = true;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timerStarted = false;
    _timer.Enabled=false;
}

void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Enabled = timerStarted;
}
```

---

Oh, and by the way: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but an ASP.NET page is *not* something that runs for a longer time. The code is executed once on the server and the HTML is passed back to the client. So what you want may not work at all.

Comment: That Worked Fine but the event call itself two time.... what I am trying to do in _timer_Elapsed event is to create a backup of a table after every 24 hour is there any other way around??

Comment: The event is called two times because you are assigning the event handler within the button click. so every time you click the button, the same event is added to the event chain. Click two times, event handler is called two times, click three times, etc. The solution to your problem is to not do the database backup from your aspx project, but (if it is SQL server) to create a backup job in the database or (if that is not a supported feature) create a console application that does the backup which you can schedule using the Windows Task Planner.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the code as below

```
public partial class TimerScheduler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       _timer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed); //to avoid multiple linking of event
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    }
    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        _timer.Enabled=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just Subscribe to the `ElapsedEvent` outside the `Button1_Click` event handler and start the `Timer` in `Button1_Click` event handler.

```
System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
_timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    _timer.Start();
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference for his problem, does it? The only difference is that pressing start over and over assigns the same event more than once, resulting in the method being called more than once.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: it may not, but i suspect that OP is clicking Button1 multiple times.

Comment: I rather suspect he didn't think of the fact that using a timer on an asp.net page may not make sense or work the way he thinks it would.-

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: thats true, i just saw the `asp.net` tag.

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference for me :( @ThorstenDittmar can you please tell me what I should do in asp instead of timer ??